# Link_to rails causing routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, hyperlink, increment, assets

so I have a simple model songs with title and likes as attributes.

I display it in a table form on the songs index page. I want to increment the number of likes upon clicking a link.

I have this in my view currently :

```
 <td> <%= link_to 'LIKE',  :action => "update", :remote => true%> </td>
```

in my songs_controller.rb i have :

```
def update
  @song = Song.find(params[:id])                                                                                                                                
  @song.likes +=1
```

I get this error on clicking link:

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets"
```

I know this is basic, will someone please help me understand what is going on here?

Thank you

UPDATE!!!!!!!  i put this following in my application.rb 
    config.assets.enabled = false

but I still get this:

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :remote=>true, :controller=>"songs"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your `:action` argument to make sure the router realizes the `:remote` argument is not part of your path:

```
<%= link_to 'LIKE', {:action => "update"}, :remote => true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good answer I found when having trouble with the same thing.
[Rails 3 how to add a custom method to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447596/rails-3-how-to-add-a-custom-method-to-controller)

This post also has a good link to a railscast which explains part of the problem too.